# Try still works even if there is an error

Tags: java, swing, try-catch, jlist

I have 2 radio buttons and pressed it in the order a->b->a I expect the output to be like a(doesn't print anything)->b(prints "N removes M")->a(prints M removes N), but what I get is a(doesn't print anything)->b(prints "N removes M")->a(prints M removes M). Why is that so? =( (btw I'm new here and a beginner in Java programming)

```
public GUI() {
    militarytonorm = new JRadioButton("Military Time to Standard Time", false);
    normtomilitary = new JRadioButton("Standard Time to Military Time", false);
    add(militarytonorm);
    add(normtomilitary);
    group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(militarytonorm);
    group.add(normtomilitary);
    checkButton ButtonChecker = new checkButton();
    militarytonorm.addActionListener(ButtonChecker);
    normtomilitary.addActionListener(ButtonChecker);
}
private class checkButton implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent MTNButton) {
        if (MTNButton.getSource() == militarytonorm) {
            if (x == 1) {
                try {
                    getContentPane().remove(Mtext);
                    getContentPane().remove(Minputhr);
                    getContentPane().remove(Minputmin);
                    getContentPane().remove(Minputsec);
                    getContentPane().remove(doneButton);
                    System.out.print("M removes M");
                } catch (Exception error) {
                    getContentPane().remove(Ntext);
                    getContentPane().remove(Ninputhr);
                    getContentPane().remove(Ninputmin);
                    getContentPane().remove(Ninputsec);
                    getContentPane().remove(AMPM);
                    getContentPane().remove(NTMButton);
                    System.out.print("M removes N");
                }
            }
            Mtext = new JLabel("input military hours, minutes and seconds");
            add(Mtext);
            Minputhr = new JFormattedTextField("00");
            Minputhr.setColumns(2);
            add(Minputhr);
            Minputmin = new JFormattedTextField("00");
            Minputmin.setColumns(2);
            add(Minputmin);
            Minputsec = new JFormattedTextField("00");
            Minputsec.setColumns(2);
            add(Minputsec);
            doneButton = new JButton("Done");
            add(doneButton);
            MTNthehandler handler = new MTNthehandler();
            doneButton.addActionListener(handler);
            x = 1;
        } else if (MTNButton.getSource() == normtomilitary) {
            if (x == 1) {
                try {
                    getContentPane().remove(Ntext);
                    getContentPane().remove(Ninputhr);
                    getContentPane().remove(Ninputmin);
                    getContentPane().remove(Ninputsec);
                    getContentPane().remove(AMPM);
                    getContentPane().remove(NTMButton);
                    System.out.print("N removes N");
                } catch (Exception error) {
                    getContentPane().remove(Mtext);
                    getContentPane().remove(Minputhr);
                    getContentPane().remove(Minputmin);
                    getContentPane().remove(Minputsec);
                    getContentPane().remove(doneButton);
                    System.out.print("N removes M");
                }
            }
            Ntext = new JLabel("input standard hours, minutes and seconds");
            add(Ntext);
            Ninputhr = new JFormattedTextField("00");
            Ninputhr.setColumns(2);
            add(Ninputhr);
            Ninputmin = new JFormattedTextField("00");
            Ninputmin.setColumns(2);
            add(Ninputmin);
            Ninputsec = new JFormattedTextField("00");
            Ninputsec.setColumns(2);
            add(Ninputsec);
            AMPM = new JList(AMorPM);
            AMPM.setVisibleRowCount(2);
            AMPM.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            add(new JScrollPane(AMPM));
            selectList AMPMSelect = new selectList();
            AMPM.addListSelectionListener(AMPMSelect);
            NTMButton = new JButton("Done");
            add(NTMButton);
            NTMthehandler NTMhandler = new NTMthehandler();
            NTMButton.addActionListener(NTMhandler);
            x = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the original Q: with the posted code nobody can say what happens. Probably post more code or a short self containing example that shows the problem.

Comment: Will this be enough?

Comment: It should be always so much code, so others can compile, run and reproduce it. Where is `x`from, where is it used elsewhere, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A note to start with: this is very complicated code - it would be much simpler if you based your GUI on a tabbed pane (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) with one tab for "Military Time to Standard Time" and a second tab for "Standard Time to Military Time".

---

To explain the behaviour you are seeing:

1. The first time you press the "militarytonorm" radio button, `x` is 0 so the code won't try to remove anything and nothing is printed. Then you create a JLabel, store a reference in Mtext and add it to the root pane (plus several more, but for the problem these are not relevant.)
2. If you now press the "normtomilitary" radio button, `x` is 1 so you try to remove Ntext from the content pane. Since Ntext is not initialized yet this will throw a NullPointerException which is caught with `catch (Exception error)` and the code removes the Mtext label and prints "N removes M".

Up until now everything as you expected.

**BUT**:

If you now press the "militarytonorm" radio button, `x` is 1 and the code tries to remove the Mtext label. Since Mtext is a valid reference to a JLabel instance the code will not throw an exception! All those `getContentPane().remove(Mxxxx)` will do nothing (since all of the components have already been removed in step 2 above) and then "M removes M" is printed.